# Save userform as .xlsx on users desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I have two buttons on UserForm: one for saving UserForm to PDF and another one for saving to XLSX. PDF works fine, I just wanted to add XLSX possibility, but can't get it work. XLSX version works only after saving to PDF. Then if I make some modifications to UserForm (number changes etc.) save to XLSX does not work again and I have to save to PDF first. Otherwise I am getting an error below. Why it is so?

Error handler points to `newWB.PasteSpecial Format:=0`

[image]

API:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Const VK_SNAPSHOT = 44
Const VK_LMENU = 164
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2
Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1
```

PrintScreen:

```
Private Sub AltPrintScreen()
    keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub
```

Save to PDF:

```
Private Sub btnPrintPDF_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next

    Dim pdfName As String
    Dim newWS As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Call AltPrintScreen

    DoEvents 

    Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
With newWS.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesTall = 1
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
    newWS.PasteSpecial Format:=0, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    pdfName = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("P14").Value & "," & " " & "Summary" & "_" & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".pdf"
newWS.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=pdfName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
    newWS.Delete

On Error GoTo 0

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set newWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Save to XLSX:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim NewBook As Workbook
    Dim newWB As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.PrintCommunication = False

    Call AltPrintScreen

    DoEvents

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set newWB = ActiveSheet
    With NewBook
       newWB.Range("A1").Select
       newWB.PasteSpecial Format:=0
       .SaveAs FileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("P14").Value & "," & " " & "Summary" & "_" & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx"
       .Close False
    End With


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set newWB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe the clipboard is being cleared? (Not sure if it that would cause the error.) Can you put `AltPrintScreen` just before the paste line.

Comment: You are missing at least one Dim statement in there... `Dim NewBook As Workbook`

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, just have tried everything without success.

Comment: `With NewBook` `.newWB.Range("A1").Select` `.newWB.PasteSpecial Format:=0`. Note the full stop before `newWB`. Without that if another workbook is active it will reference the active sheet in that workbook. Have you tried including the `fileformat` parameter for the `Save As` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)?